# HackerRank Ransom Note challenge

Tags: python, performance

I'm solving HackerRank "Ransom Note" challenge. The code runs fine and cracks it, but I have an issue with its performance. It times out in some cases.

> A kidnapper wrote a ransom note but is worried it will be traced back
>   to him. He found a magazine and wants to know if he can cut out whole
>   words from it and use them to create an untraceable replica of his
>   ransom note. The words in his note are case-sensitive and he must use
>   whole words available in the magazine, meaning he cannot use
>   substrings or concatenation to create the words he needs.
>
> Given the words in the magazine and the words in the ransom note,
>   print Yes if he can replicate his ransom note exactly using whole
>   words from the magazine; otherwise, print No.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers describing the
>   respective values of (the number of words in the magazine) and (the
>   number of words in the ransom note).
>
> The second line contains space-separated strings denoting the words
>   present in the magazine.
>
> The third line contains space-separated strings denoting the words
>   present in the ransom note.

My implementation:

```
def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    for word in ransom:
        if word in magazine:
            magazine.remove(word)
        else:
            return False
    return True

m, n = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))
magazine = input().strip().split(' ')
ransom = input().strip().split(' ')
answer = ransom_note(magazine, ransom)
if(answer):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

It's timing out when there are too many items (30.000) on `magazine` or `ransom`. Performance talking, what can I improve here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop has a potential complexity of R * M (R number of words in ransom, M number of words in magazine). Additionally you use `remove` in the inner loop which which does linear search in magazine.

The solution is to count occurences of words in both, magazine and ransom. this is done in a single sweep and of linear complexity R + M (dict get/set is average linear).

the moste dense and readable solution is

```
from collections import Counter

def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    ran = Counter(ransom)
    mag = Counter(magazine)
    return len(ran - mag) == 0
```

if you assume a very long magazine and a short ransom message you could go for an early break by counting the ransom first, then do a down count with magazine words. magazine could be a generator in that case reading from an arbitrary large file.

```
from collections import Counter

def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    ran = Counter(ransom)
    if not ran:
        return True # handle edge case
    for m in magazine:
        if m in ran:
            # we need this word
            if ran[m] > 1:
                ran[m] -= 1
                # still need more of that one
            else:
                # the last usage of this word
                ran.pop(m)
                if len(ran) == 0:
                    # we found the last word of our ransom
                    return True
    return False
```

Comment: @Peilonrayz - you are right, thanks. fixed my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If we consider length of a magazine, \$N\$, and length of ransom note, M, your current code checks each word in the ransom note, m, up to \$n\$ (# of words in the magazine) times. This results in \$O(N*M)\$.

Instead of searching through the entire magazine word list again and again, it's possible to hash each word in the magazine and store a count along with it. Then, when you want to check if a word is in the magazine, you can check the hash in \$O(1)\$ time for a result of \$O(N)\$ to construct the hash and \$O(M)\$ to check all m words, which is a final \$O(N+M)\$.

In Python, you can construct this word/count dictionary with a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def ransom_note(magazine, ransom):
    word_counts = Counter(magazine)
    for word in ransom:
        if word_counts[word] > 0:
            word_counts[word] -= 1
        else:
            return False
    return True
```